# How to convert the cell values in comma separated value in excel?

Tags: excel

Can anyone help me with an excel formula that groups related rows and creates a comma separated value result.

Original:

```
State   city
WB  city1
WB  city2
WB  city3
WB  city4
WB  city5
Kar banga
kar Mysore
```

Expected:

```
State   city
WB  ciry1,city2,city3,city4,city5
Kar banga,Mysore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for here is something like a for loop which formula's in excel do not provide.You need to write some code to do this, the best way in excel is to break down your task in to 3 stages:

1. Identify the unique states and list them as column headers
2. Using a if formula statement, get all the values that match the column headers and list them down that specific row. Ex: =IF(C5=D$4,D4,"") (Drag this formula all the way down)
3. Using a concatenate formula, concatenate the columns so that you get your final solution.

If this will meet your needs, I can expand exact formulas required.

Comment: Please provide me the formula for stpe2.

Comment: Seanog this is high level guidance - as such this is a comment at best not an answer

Comment: See formula above.  Note $ is used so that when the formula is dragged down the heading value D4 does not change.